# Using having in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, having-clause

I want to merge the following queries to get the answer I want. But I don't seem to get it right.

**Query 1:**

```
select a.idlisting, count(p.idpostulant) as Total_postulants
from postulations p
inner join listings a on p.idlisting = a.idlisting
where a.idate >= '2014-07-01'
and a.idate < '2014-08-01'
group by a.idlisting
having total_postulants > 500
```

With the answer I get from the first query I complete the **idlisting** clause

```
**Query 2:**

select count(distinct p.idpostulant)
from postulations p
inner join listings a on p.idlisting = a.idlisting
where a.idlisting in ('1001972582',
'1001964448',
'1001926936')
```

The answer should be the amount of **unique** postulants that subscribe to all the **listings** that have over 500 postulations.

Please let me know if it's understandable.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `join` and subqueries:

```
select count(distinct p.idpostulant)
from postulations p inner join
     listings a
     on p.idlisting = a.idlisting inner join
     (select a.idlisting, count(p.idpostulant) as Total_postulants
      from postulations p inner join
           listings a
           on p.idlisting = a.idlisting
      where a.idate >= '2014-07-01' and a.idate < '2014-08-01'
      group by a.idlisting
      having total_postulants > 500
     ) filter
     on a.idlisting = filter.idlisting;
```

EDIT:

You can slightly simplify the above query by removing one of the joins in the outer query:

```
select count(distinct p.idpostulant)
from postulations p inner join
     (select a.idlisting, count(p.idpostulant) as Total_postulants
      from postulations p inner join
           listings a
           on p.idlisting = a.idlisting
      where a.idate >= '2014-07-01' and a.idate < '2014-08-01'
      group by a.idlisting
      having total_postulants > 500
     ) filter
     on p.idlisting = filter.idlisting;
```

Comment: Your query worked, but it took two minutes to fetch the answer. I'll try the other answer I have left to see which one is more efficient.

Comment: @Pietro . . . It is hard to know if that is reasonable without knowing about the size of your current data and the indexing structure.

Comment: One of the tables is big, lisitng is 7GB and postulations 80GB

Answer (score 1):

Just putting the first query in the 'in' clause should work.  Or are you looking for a cleaner version?

```
select count(distinct p.idpostulant)
from postulations p
inner join listings a on p.idlisting = a.idlisting
where a.idlisting in (
      select a.idlisting
      from postulations p
      inner join listings a on p.idlisting = a.idlisting
      where a.idate >= '2014-07-01'
      and a.idate < '2014-08-01'
      group by a.idlisting
      having count(p.idpostulant) > 500)
```

Comment: Nop, that throws an error. Operand should contain 1 column

Comment: oops, forgot to remove the second column I'll fix it.

Comment: No, error again. total_postulants is an alias from the count function.

Comment: made one more change to the having clause

Comment: your answer should work, but the problem is that is taking too long to fetch me the result. I didn't clarify that both tables are very big. Aprox 20GB and 60GB

Comment: I could see that being a problem